# Is there any documentation around verifying that the data sent is the same data received by Firestore (.set)?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

Is there an implicit checksumming or anything Google Firestore does automatically to ensure the data sent from an endpoint is the same data that arrives in the Firestore Database?
This is not about security rules. This is verifying the data sent from an authorized source is not corrupted or corroded in any way between endpoints.

Comment: Presumably the data is sent over HTTP, which is built on top of [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol). The TCP protocol ensures [data integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Data_transfer)

Answer (score 1):

@kwsp's hunch was on the right track.

As per https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/server-side-encryption, Firestore uses TLS which you can read about the data integrity here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Data_integrity